# SQL Query FInd average of KPI ID for Each employee ID

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want query statement to find the average for each KPI for each employee ID

Target table:

```
-----------------------------------
ID       | KPI_ID     | Scoure    |
-----------------------------------
8543     | 5          | 1800      |
8543     | 5          | 1600      |
8543     | 3          | 80        |
9123     | 5          | 1400      |
9123     | 2          | 60        |
3789     | 1          | 40        |
8543     | 5          | 1400      |
8543     | 2          | 50        |
9123     | 5          | 1600      |
9123     | 1          | 70        |
3789     | 1          | 70        |
----------------------------------
```

Output table:

```
-----------------------------------
ID       | KPI_ID     | AVG_Scoure|
-----------------------------------
8543     | 5          | 1600      |
8543     | 3          | 80        |
9123     | 5          | 1500      |
9123     | 2          | 60        |
3789     | 1          | 55        |
8543     | 2          | 50        |
9123     | 1          | 70        |
----------------------------------
```

Comment: This looks like a basic `AVG .... GROUP BY` query. Have you tried anything apart from asking here? Done any research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An information that is still needed is your DBMS, by the way your query should be like this:

```
SELECT ID, KPI_ID, Round(avg(Scoure)) AS AVG_Scoure
FROM tmpTable
GROUP BY ID, KPI_ID;
```

For more information and details check this SQLFiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e2d6/2.
You can even change the DBMS and check if it still works for yours.

Comment: Great, But the AVG_Scoure column double i want to keep it integer

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I Modified the Query to keep the AVG_Scoure as int. Check this link for more information. [Round function in MS Access](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/numeric/round.php)

Comment: how can i edited the query ?

Comment: I updated my answer correctly. Check it now.